# s3cmd sync not setting ACL to public

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use s3cmd on ubuntu 10.04 to sync with a local folder. This is working great for getting the contents from the local drive out to S3. However, I want the file ACL to be "public", yet all the files are coming through without it.

In my .s3cfg file, I set:

```
acl_public = True
```

I've tried:

```
s3cmd sync -P --delete-removed "$TARGETFOLDER" "s3://$BUCKET/"
```

I've also tried:

```
s3cmd sync --acl-public --delete-removed "$TARGETFOLDER" "s3://$BUCKET/"
```

And, for kicks, also tried this:

```
s3cmd sync -P --acl-public --delete-removed "$TARGETFOLDER" "s3://$BUCKET/"
```

Any ideas?

**Update**

I have set the ACL on the target bucket as Read/Write/Full-Control for authenticated users and administrator, and read-only for Everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Turns out the files were accessible all along and being set as "public-read", but S3 Organizer in Firefox was not reflecting this through the ACL permissions popup window.

Comment: Could you clarify which of the 3 commands you tried worked with setting the permissions? I don't want to put `acl_public = True` in my .s3cfg because that would make every command use acl_public for everything.

Answer (score 15):

I tried it out right now. 
Making things public while synching can definitely be achieved with the *acl-public* option:

```
s3cmd sync --acl-public s3://source-bucket/ s3://target-bucket/
```

Comment: It seems to me that only the files that get added during the sync get the public ACL, while the existing files retain the old ACL.